# dynamic array declaration in arduino

Tags: arduino, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to make a code that unlocks a door when a correct passcode is given. But, while doing that, I came across a problem. I had to store the passcode entered in a dynamic array. I know that there is a package for making a dynamic array But I don't know the code for making the dynamic array. I am posting the code I have done till now that is, only starting up the keypad.

```
#include <Keypad.h>
const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 4;
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
{'1','2','3','A'},
{'4','5','6','B'},
{'7','8','9','C'},
{'*','0','#','D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = { 8, 7, 6, 9 };
byte colPins[COLS] = { 5, 4, 3, 2 };
Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup() {

  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: In general, that's a simple C++ question, But I don't understand, why you need a dynamic array. Your problem is rather to store the correct passcode even when the arduino is powered off.

Comment: I need a dynamic array to store the user's input

Comment: You don't need to store more user input than you have for the correct passcode. Just provide for 8 keys, e.g. (That would even fit into a single uint32_t, but 8 bytes are probably easier)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int* dynamicArray;
dynamicArray = new int[arraySize];
if(dynamicArray == nullptr) {
    //if memory could not be assigned
}
//do stuff with your array
delete[] dynamicArray; //delete when not in use anymore
```

Comment: Try to do more than "code only" answers in the future.